# Mongodump archive record count

Tags: mongodb, bash, stdout, mongodump

I'm working on a document backup solution that needs to be bulletproof.   Im running my backup each week, and Im able to do a dryrun before the actual dump to determine how many documents I am going to dump.  So, I have a target number.

Issue is, when I actually RUN the mongodump, it writes all output to the CONSOLE, not to stdout.  So I cant capture the output to a variable, find the number of documents it dumped, and compare to my target number.

Ive also looked and dont see any way to use mongorestore to get a record count in the file after the fact.

And no, wc -l doesnt work.

So, this is what I see written to console during the mongodump:

```
2022-03-03T22:25:15.069+0000    writing mydb.records to archive '/opt/weekly/records_2022-02-13'
2022-03-03T22:25:17.529+0000    mydb.records  101
2022-03-03T22:25:22.510+0000    mydb.records  1675
2022-03-03T22:25:22.513+0000    done dumping mydb.records (1675 documents)
```

The above is going to console, and Im not able to capture it from within my script (i.e. varname=$(mongodumpcommandhere) ), nor am I able to redirect the output to a .log file and then scrub the contents.

So, any mongo experts out there know how I can do what I want?   Sure, Im already checking the exit status of the mongodump command, just trying to go the extra mile and line up the document count as well.

I could install a blank DB and load the dump and count the documents, but that seems like a little far to go just to get the number of documents in a dump.  Looking for something a little less brute force.

Oh, and this is a bash script handling all of the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongodumpcommandhere` may be writing to standard error instead of standard output.  If that is the case

```
 varname=$(mongodumpcommandhere 2>&1)
```

will work.  If it doesn't work it probably means that the command is writing directly to the terminal.  That's a bad thing to do, but there are ways to capture it.

Comment: So, that DID suppress the output, I'm not seeing the above output now.  But still nothing inside 'varname'.

Comment: @R.Smith, that is very mysterious.  The *only* effect of `2>&1` is to make standard error output go to standard output instead.  The job of `$(...)` is to capture data sent to standard output.  If you also try to capture the output to a file (`varname=$(mongodumpcommandhere 2>&1 | tee dumpout.txt)`) is there anything in the `dumpout.txt` file?

Comment: So, I was subject to "too many edits" syndrome.  I had many versions of the command commented and ended up adding the stderr redirect to one that was also redirecting to a file.  So something like "$(mongocommand > out.txt 2>&1).  And yes, the actual file DID contain the output I'm looking for.  Upon re-reading the code, saw the issue, checked the file, and then updated the script.  And yes, I now have what i need, just need to parse it. It was the fact that it vanished from the screen but didn't end up in the var that kept me looking at it.  Thanks for the solution I needed!!

Comment: @R.Smith, thanks for the update.  It's good to hear that it worked out.